# 64-bit proxy stub dll registry entry under WOW64?

Tags: windows, com

When we register a 64-bit proxy stub dll on a 64-bit OS(Win7) , we observe that entires in the registry are made under WOW6432Node as well along with 64-bit entry .  Ideally we do not expect a WOW6432 entry .

Comment: Could be a feature of the DLL's DllRegisterServer implementation.  Registering both 32-bit and 64-bit keys is entirely reasonable for an out-of-process server.